# writing documentation of angular projects using grunt-ngdocs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation-generation

I want to document an angular project I am working on. I tried `grunt-ngdocs`. It looks simple with less configuration and the initial trials look nice and promising. But I couldn't find a good resource on its complete usage. The limited documentation on the tool is confusing.

These are the links I have gone through:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation

https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs

If you have any good resource on this tool, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this guide, I think is very useful:

http://www.podpea.co.uk/blog/starting-off-with-ngdocs/

Comment: Hey, @miguelr, the Link is expired, do you know another link or can you post it here?